# Add values when there is a gap between elements

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have a list defined as

```
A = [1.0, 3.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0]
```

I am trying to fill the gap between the elements of the list with zero values. A gap is an increment between elements that is more than one. So for instance between 1.0 and 3.0 there is one gap: 2.0 and between 3.0 and 6.0 there are two gaps:4.0 and 5.0

I am working with this code but it is not complete and I am missing adding multiple values when the gap is bigger than one increment

```
B = []
cnt = 0
for i in range(len(A)-1):
    if A[i] == A[i+1] - 1:
        B.append(A[cnt])
        cnt += 1
    if A[i] != A[i+1] - 1:
        B.append(A[cnt])
        B.append(0.0)
        cnt += 1
```

The output of this code is:

```
B = [1.0, 0.0, 3.0, 0.0, 6.0, 7.0]
```

But since there are two gaps between 3.0 and 6.0 I need B to look like this:

```
B = [1.0, 0.0, 3.0, 0.0, 0.0, 6.0, 7.0]
```

I am a bit stuck on how to do this and I already have a feeling that my code is not very optimized. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: What should the output look like if the input is `[1.0, 3.5, 7.0]`?

Comment: `[float(x) for x in range(int(min(A)), int(max(A)))]` ?

Comment: The values I am dealing with are always integers actually but represented as floats for certain reasons outside the scope of the question but thank you for raising the point

Comment: @Ingaz, OP wants to fill gaps with `0.0` but your output is like this: `[1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0]`

Comment: @DariaPydorenko: My bad! `[(float(x) if float(x) in A else 0.0)  for x in range(int(min(A)), int(max(A))) ] `

Comment: I want to be able to index the line I am adding an element with, this is why I started with using a counter

Comment: @mrcbrbr, I've rolled your modification back. It's already got 27 views and 2 answers. We don't want a disjointed Q&A. You can attempt a solution yourself and, if you get stuck, post a separate question.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a list comprehension. Assuming your list is ordered, you can extract the first and last indices of `A`. We use `set` for O(1) lookup complexity within the comprehension.

```
A = [1.0, 3.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0]
A_set = set(A)
res = [i if i in A_set else 0 for i in range(int(A[0]), int(A[-1])+1)]

print(res)

[1, 0, 3, 0, 0, 6, 7, 8]
```

However, for larger arrays I'd recommend you use a specialist library such as NumPy:

```
import numpy as np

A = np.array([1.0, 3.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0]).astype(int)
B = np.zeros(A.max())
B[A-1] = A

print(B)

array([ 1.,  0.,  3.,  0.,  0.,  6.,  7.,  8.])
```

Comment: What about C? Is it possible to do the same for C?

Comment: @mrcbrbr, I've rolled your question back. It's already got 27 views and 2 answers. We don't want a disjointed Q&A. You can attempt a solution yourself and, if you get stuck, post a separate question.

Answer (score 1):

Based on comments to the question, I can suggest the following solution:

```
B = [float(x) if x in A else 0.0 for x in range(int(min(A)), int(max(A)) + 1)]
```